# Folder structure for a big website (JS project)

Tags: javascript

I am going to write a project of a website and use JavaScript, HTML, LESS. Also I will have a lot of images almost for every HTML file.

Which is the best folders' layout for a typical website?

Comment: As far as I know, you should follow a modular approach i.e divide each module and have a similar pattern for each module. You can have folders for each module like js, css, tests, controllers, views, etc.
Otherwise, you  can try  yo generators which create an initial scaffolding for you. Or you can try MEAN stack

Comment: @Rudra, thank you. Do you have any example to show?

Comment: First step for you is to decide on the framework which you are going to use. If you are ok with mean, there are a lot of resources available online. follow http://meanjs.org/

Answer (score 1):

you can take a look at [yeoman](http://yeoman.io/)
It's a scaffolding tool for generating web sites, web apps.. 
there are many "generators" available.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a full stack and advance architectured code.
You can try http://meanjs.org/

The best thing about this full stack framework is it comes with unit testing and other useful codes for developing large scale websites.